# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Do we know when the selected moderators will be announced?

Comment: @RichardSeal: I'm getting ready to send out invitations via email now. Depending on how quickly people respond, I should have an announcement by next week.

Answer (score 42):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Mark is the driving force behind Sitecore Stack Exchange. It looks like this site is his home. He started out by making the site proposal on Area51, and then managed the whole process: engaging the community; asking a lot of good questions; providing detailed and insightful answers; communicating with the SE management; and overall being the most active user on the site, which is reflected by his reputation numbers.

He has consistently showed that he cares about [**the community**](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/), about content quality and about [**doing the right thing**](https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/).

I believe he would make a top-notch moderator.

**EDIT - Nominee Response**

I accept this nomination, and appreciate the support given to this community from everyone involved.

So many of you know me. I'm a Sitecore Communitist (err), been active in the Sitecore Social Sphere since early 2006. Plenty of war stories to trade. Generally driven by enthusiasm mixed with a fair measure of OCD in wanting to make everything I get involved in, as best as can be.

I am mostly online during European timezones but have been known to roam around into the wee hours of the morning as well.

I am based in Switzerland. Yes everything runs like clockwork here. No I will not send you any chocolate ;-)

Comment: After being on the [receiving end of an aggressive series of comments from Mark Cassidy](http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1538/286), I do not feel that he is ready for a moderating role in this community.

Comment: I'm quite convinced any of my comments can stand up to scrutiny - none were agressive. You, on the other hand, refuse to respond to constructive critisism and - in my experience - fail to respond to community efforts to keep the site consistent.

Comment: Agreed, I do not feel that the comments in question were aggressive at all, and the community at large seems to be in agreement with Mark.

Comment: @MarkCassidy, you had called me a "special snowflake" and later called me a troll. I do not feel that resorting to argumentum ad hominem is behavior that is acceptable for a moderator. How you behave toward people you disagree with is probably the most important part of being a moderator.

Comment: That's your opinion and you are of course entitled to it.

Comment: I would like to vocally toss support to @MarkCassidy. He has been the cornerstone and lynch-pin of this initiative and has demonstrated himself as an example to us all on the level of activity and quality that we should all embody. It would be remiss, not to have him be one of the first moderators.

Comment: Mark, I honestly mean no disrespect, and this was hard to write. I am torn on this one. Mark has done nothing but show his dedication to this community and has gone above and beyond to make sure that Sitecore Stack Exchange becomes a reality. However, one of the key qualities I believe a moderator needs to have is the ability to remain a neutral and calm voice even when a storm is happening. The recent interactions with zzzzBov, whatever best intentions may have been at the heart of it, are not exemplary of the type of moderator activity I would like to see in our community.

Comment: Jay, can you exemplify please?  The user in question has conveniently deleted the comment thread that is now being wrongly quoted out of context as an argument against me. Above in this very comment thread, John confirms they did not come across as inappropriate. That said; I feel it unfair to be judged on standards of a moderator when - in fact - moderator tools was exactly what could have made this issue resolve quietly and without fuss. Tools that are not available to any of us at this point.

Comment: Hi Mark, I agree that the deletion of the comment thread is unfortunate. This meta post: http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/129/my-post-was-being-edited-against-my-will-and-now-it-is-being-plagiarized-what
is what I can find of the remaining conversation. I find no issues with what you did as an edit, nor in the language used, My concern was over the use of a confrontational approach. For example, "The simple answer:

You're expected to fall in line with the standards we put in place during Commitment and Closed Beta."

This is accurate, yet confrontational.

Comment: It is. Given tools available, the leadup to this post and feedback happening in real time on Slack while these events took place - I believe confrontation was in order. The feedback I got and am still getting is, that the user in question was ranging between "out of line" to "extremely rude and provocative". The post you are referring to, however, is out of bounds and is mostly concerned with name calling rather than debate the actual issue at hand - which is our policies and unwritten guidelines on community edits, and the incident with the plagiarised post, action that wasn't mine.

Comment: In light of this incident however, there are significant take aways. We've opened up Meta posts debating quality of content. http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/136/what-makes-a-good-post and http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/144/what-are-community-edits-and-why-do-we-do-them. Both aimed as linkable points of reference - to avoid discussions like these in the future.

Comment: I forgot to add; the purpose of posts such as these examples is to add objective guidelines for moderation. As it is right now - all we have is the collective result of the Beta - to moderate the site at this stage requires extensive understanding on how the community edited and reacted during the beta. Later on, we will have enough of these "guideline posts" to make the process more transparent.

Comment: I for one support Mark. I understand some people may find things offensive that others (or most don't) but this is a community site so majority rules. I also believe the name calling mentioned should be considered as humor, and they were posted as a user, not as an admin.

Comment: Mark has been the driving force behind the Stackexchange site. For me there is no doubt that he should be a moderator.

Comment: I second the proposal to make Mark a moderator. He is the main force behind this SE site and without him this site would not have been here.

Answer (score 36):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Richard has been an incredibly passionate and dedicated community member, and was one of the principle members during the Sitecore Stack Exchange Private Beta. His comments and edits on reviewed posts have been concise and thoughtful, all while providing solid technical answers to questions around the site. He is also already active on the existing [StackOverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316414/richard-seal), focusing on Sitecore related questions.

I believe he has the required attitude and perspective that's needed when managing large communities. He'll also be a great public face for the community as a whole, given how public the Sitecore Stack Exchange site will be.

**EDIT - Nominee Response**

I accept the nomination, and thanks to Justin for nominating me and all those that vote!

Many of you know me as GuitarRich on Slack and I have tried to be as active as I can in the community for the past couple of years. I have been working with Sitecore since early 2009 and I think I have a lot to offer to the community. We have an amazing community here and I think the Stack Exchange site is going to be a massive benefit for everyone involved!

I am based in Florida - so if anyone wants to visit some theme parks - lets have a User Group here :), mostly online EST hours, but much to the wife's annoyance most evenings too!

Comment: Likewise, I am equally voicing support for Rich Seal. It has a been a pleasure working with him in our Slack community and assisting him and Cassidy during the Private Beta. His knowledge is only unmatched by his insane guitar skills!

Comment: The commitment of Richard to the community is really impressive, always willing to help and with great knowledge. Also we need to give him something as his MVP award is still lost :).

Answer (score 31):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I have known (of) Dmytro for quite some time, during his and my active participation on Stack Overflow. His Stack Overflow record can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/236660/dmytro-shevchenko

More importantly; I have seem him carry this dedication across to our new site - this http://sitecore.stackexchange.com - he has shown commitment during the beta period, he helped pull weight when we needed it most of all, and he continues to answer questions almost faster than people can type them up.

He is passionate about the quality of his answers, demands the same from his fellow users and has a good sense of right and wrong - what goes and what does not, and overall what all of us would like this site to be.

I believe he will be an asset to this community. I also believe his extensive Stack Overflow background brings some perspective to the table, of "what makes a good Exchange site" that we could all benefit from.

#### EDIT - Nominee Response

I accept this nomination.

Hi, I am Dmytro. Since I started developing Sitecore solutions last year, I took a great interest in the Sitecore community, which is very active and diverse. I enjoy deep investigation of technical issues, I take pleasure in being helpful, and I really like to improve everything I can lay my hands on.

I am a Ukrainian currently living in Bulgaria, so I am generally active online from 6am UTC to 6pm UTC.

I believe that Sitecore Stack Exchange will soon be the best place on the internet for gaining Sitecore knowledge, as well as for finding solutions for difficult Sitecore-related problems.

Comment: It's a pleasure to read all the answers and comments that Dmytro provided. Definitely feel that he is an appropriate moderator.

Answer (score 29):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I have been a passionate and active Sitecore developer for the past 10 years. Most of my efforts have been behind the scenes working with individual developers and agencies building up strong Sitecore talent.

Over the past year, I have stepped my game up by being extremely active within the Sitecore Community. One of the downsides of the community was the water down nature that Sitecore as a topic on StackOverflow.com has become.

When Mark Cassidy announced that he was starting this Stack Exchange for Sitecore, I was extremely happy and wanted to throw everything I had into the success of this site.

I desire a site that has quality content and quality answers.  During the Private Beta, I feel that I have demonstrated a high level of dedication to this site. My answers and questions are thoughtfully constructed.

I believe that I am and can be a benefit to this community, and have no shame nominating myself. =)

#### EDIT - Nominee Response

On Behalf of myself, I accept this nomination.

My alter-ego self "[Sitecore Hacker](http://www.sitecorehacker.com)" feels they are a perfect match for any problem that might come up on this site. I live in Boston, so I am generally active on this site from 9AM Eastern to 11PM Eastern. Some other things you may want to know about me are that I enjoy long walks on the beach, for 6 years I was a tornado chaser, for 5 years an EMT, for 3 years a wedding planner/reception coordinator/disc jockey.  I am a renaissance man!

Comment: If Pete didn't nominate himself, I was going to.  He's been incredibly visible during the beta so far and insanely helpful to me.

Comment: @kyleTrauberman +1 for "insanely helpful"

Comment: What Kyle and Richard said! Not to mention the fact that he's Pete!

Comment: Go Pete! Really helpful guy

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Zach is our resident source for Sitecore information. He's the one to go to when you are really stuck on a problem. AND, he always eager to help out with an answer.

I am relatively new to Sitecore and his help in getting me up to speed has been immeasurable. There have been many times when he has gotten me out of a jam.

He is passionate about doing the best job possible at all times, even when the walls of a deadline are closing in and everyone is freaking out.

I believe the community would benefit from his expertise.

#### EDIT - Nominee Response

Thank you so much for thinking of me, Ethan. However, I must respectfully decline. The others who have been nominated so far are some of the top in the industry, and they have been putting in some incredible hours in order to make this site a reality. I will continue to be as active as possible on SSE, but I believe that the community would be better served by having Pete Navarra, Mark Cassidy, Richard Seal, and Dmytro Shevchenko as moderators. Again, thanks for thinking of me and good luck to all of the other nominees!